# Why is Django giving me this AttributeError?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, attributeerror

Django is giving me this weird AttributeeError :

'Tour' object has no attribute 'check_if_requested_beds_are_avaliable'

However, I have the method check_if_requested_beds_are_avaliable() in my Tour class of my model. The other method - set_new_number_of_beds() works fine. I have never experienced this with with Django, can anybody tell me what the solution is?

This is the model :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class  Tour(models.Model):

    destination = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    date_of_arrival = models.DateField()
    total_days = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6)
    available_beds = models.IntegerField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',default='photos/def.png')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def set_new_number_of_beds(self,number_of_guests):

        self.available_beds -= number_of_guests
        return self.available_beds

    def check_if_requested_beds_are_available(self,numb_of_guests):

        if self.available_beds < numb_of_guests:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.destination} , {self.country} , {self.total_days} days for $ {self.price}'

class Client(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    number_of_guests =models.IntegerField()
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6,default=0)


    def get_total_price(self):

        return self.number_of_guests * self.tour.price 


    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('tour_list')

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}, {self.tour}'
```

and this is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from aplikacija.models import Tour,Client,ContactMessage
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView,TemplateView,CreateView
from aplikacija.forms import ClientForm,ContactForm


def HomeView(request):

    if request.method=="GET":
        return render(request,'aplikacija/home.html')
    else:
        form= ClientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            surname=form.cleaned_data['surname']
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            tour_id=form.cleaned_data['tour'].pk
            number_of_guests=form.cleaned_data['number_of_guests']
            total_price=number_of_guests*form.cleaned_data['tour'].price
            tour_name=form.cleaned_data['tour'].destination
            client = Client.objects.create(name=name,surname=surname,email=email,number_of_guests=number_of_guests,tour_id=tour_id,total_price=total_price)
            client.save()
            tour=Tour.objects.get(destination=tour_name)
            beds_available = tour.check_if_requested_beds_are_avaliable(number_of_guests)
            if beds_available:
                tour.set_new_number_of_beds(number_of_guests)
                tour.save()
                message =f'thank you {name} ! Your reservation to {tour} for {number_of_guests} guests , with a total price of {total_price} has been booked successfully.'
                return render(request,'aplikacija/home.html',{'msg':message})
            else:
                form = ClientForm()
                return render(request,'aplikacija/client_form.html',{'infoMsg':f"sorry, there are less than {number_of_guests} beds available for {tour_name}",'form':form})
            


def thanksView(request):

    form=ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sender=form.cleaned_data['sender']
        title=form.cleaned_data['title']
        body=form.cleaned_data['body']
        message=ContactMessage.objects.create(sender=sender,title=title,body=body)
        message.save()
        return render(request,'aplikacija/thanks.html')

class TourListView(ListView):

    model = Tour

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Tour.objects.all()


class TourDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Tour

class CreateClientView(CreateView):

    redirect_field_name = "/aplikacija/home.html"
    model = Client
    form_class = ClientForm

class contactView(CreateView):

    redirect_field_name="/aplikacija/thanks.html"
    model = ContactMessage
    form_class=ContactForm
```

So , Its pretty clear that I have the method that gives the AttributeError. And like I said the other method in the class works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the full stack trace for the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the typo: check_if_requested_beds_are_av**alia**ble. Can be discovered with search or by using IDE with code completion